Error out if filtering for a non-existent level
Given this factor variable:
library(tidyverse)
a <- factor(c(1,1,1,2,2), levels=c(1,2), labels=c("Male", "Female"))

I want this to error out because Females is not a valid level:
a %>% .[.=="Male"|.=="Females"]

How can I do that?

forcats::fct_match() errors when levels aren't present, so you can do:
library(forcats)

a <- factor(c(1,1,1,2,2), levels=c(1,2), labels=c("Male", "Female"))

a %>% .[fct_match(., c("Male", "Females"))]

#> Error in `fct_match()`:
#> ! All `lvls` must be present in `f`.
#> ℹ Missing levels: "Females"

a %>% .[fct_match(., c("Male", "Female"))]

#> [1] Male   Male   Male   Female Female
#> Levels: Male Female


It's a good solution, but unfortunate you have to first convert into a dataframe

You don't, you can do a %>% .[fct_match(., c("Male", "Females"))]. Edited to your original approach.

You could trace Ops.factor:
trace(Ops.factor, tracer = quote({
  if (nzchar(.Method[1L])) stopifnot("Comparing factor with value not in levels" = 
                                       all(e2 %in% levels(e1)))
  if (nzchar(.Method[2L])) stopifnot("Comparing factor with value not in levels" = 
                                       all(e1 %in% levels(e2)))
}), at = 1, print = FALSE)
#Tracing function "Ops.factor" in package "base"

"Females" == a
#Error in Ops.factor("Females", a) : 
#  Comparing factor with value not in levels

"Female" == a
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

untrace(Ops.factor)

PS: I would want to test the tracer with some edge cases if I intended to use it in production code.

What edge cases do you have in mind?

Different classes of the non-factor, NA, NaN, Inf, ...

Adding a line involving stopifnot before that command will invoke an error -  if that's what you're after.
{
  stopifnot(any(levels(a) %in% "Females"))
  a %>% .[.=="Male"|.=="Females"]
}

Or make it a bit more general:
{
  a1 <- "Male"
  a2 <- "Females"
  
  stopifnot("Error. Invalid factor level." = all(c(a1, a2) %in% levels(a)))
  a %>% .[.==a1|.==a2]
}


This is verbose. I guess I need a cutostom-type that allows me to do this?
